# Regex to fetch a line by the matching the last word , but the lastword should not be selected

Tags: regex

i need a regular expression needs to fetch a line which has one matching word at the end. It should select the line without selecting the lastword.

For e.g

abc = new obj(); //object OBJECT_CREATION

Regex should select the above statement which has the OBJECT_CREATION at the end but it should select upto the below one. OBJECT_CREATION keyword should be used to identify the line and it should not be selected.

Expected output

abc = new obj(); //object

Is it possible to get that?

Comment: Do you want a generic expression which skips all last words. This is answered by Avinash Raj, but it will match almost every line. If you want to match a line before a specific last word, the expression has to be modified slightly

Comment: Yes i want to match a line , which has the specific last word , but the last word should not come in the selected line. Last word should be used to just identify the line.

Comment: Did you try something like `.*.(?= +OBJECT_CREATION(?!.))` [see test](https://regex101.com/r/bL2vG4/1). Or if multiline flag available: `(?m)^.+(?= +OBJECT_CREATION$)`. If the space can contain tabs try `[\t ]+` before `OBJECT`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the last word along with the preceding space character with an empty string.

```
string.replaceAll("\\s*\\S+$", "");
```

or

```
string.replaceAll("\\s*\\S+\\s*$", "");
```

**OR**

Matche all the chars upto the last space.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(?= )");
```

or

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(?=\\s)");
```

Comment: I need to pass only regex and i dont have the access to the code ,In the regex itself i want to do that.

Comment: check the alternative option.